# php filter array of image names and show missing @2x retina images

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I have a folder of a lot of images for in iPad app. Trying to create an automated php script to check to see if all the images that are in the folder have a paired non-retina and retina image set. If the retina image is not present, display a message saying something like: "Missing: $filename" where $filename is the value... I am coming up short on how to do a compare of the array of images grabbed via glob():

First i get the images from the folder that are jpg or png:

```
$images = glob("ipad/{*.jpg,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Now i want to check this array of images to show the missing @2x image sets... I was reading that you could use array_filter but don't quite get how to do this...

Any ideas how to achieve this and then echo them out with a foreach "Missing: $filename"

Comment: By paired, you mean that you have given consistent names to the two images of the pair (e.g. `myimg.jpg` and `myimg-retina. jpg`) or you want to find whether an image is the duplicate of another one at a bigger size, whatever the image is named?

Comment: Yah basically look for image.png and see if there is an image@2x.png counterpart... If 2x version is non existent display the name of the file that needs the 2x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$path = __DIR__;
$all = glob("$path/*.{jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

$normal = $retina = array();

// Group Images
foreach($all as $v) {
    strpos($v, '@2x') === false and $normal[basename($v)] = $v;
    strpos($v, '@2x') !== false and $retina[basename($v)] = $v;
}

foreach($normal as $image) {
    $v = pathinfo($image);
    $name = $v['filename'] . '@2x.' . $v['extension'];
    if (! isset($retina[$name])) {
        echo "Missing: $name\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is producing a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION any idea why? on the $normal = ... line of code

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: That is the reason ... PHP 5.2.17 does not support closures .. have updated the code .. but please update your PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
var_dump(array_filter(glob('ipad/{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE), function ($file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    return !preg_match('/@2x$/', $info['filename'])
        && !file_exists("$info[dirname]/$info[filename]@2x.$info[extension]");
}));
```